# What is involved in converting a Silverlight application to run "Out of Browser"?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

What is involved in converting a Silverlight application to run "Out of Browser"? We have an established application and would like to know what kinds of things we need to be aware of if we decide to make this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(v=VS.95).aspx[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

to see what you can and can't do and other features

Answer (score 1):

Two main things that I experienced first hand about OOB

- If you have an normal silverlight(non-OOB) app now, you will have to change your solution settings and recompile to get OOB options.
- The updates to your silverlight app are not very transparent (involves restart of the client at the very least)

Comment: -yeah. the update process is a bummer but out-of browser concept is very refreshing.

Comment: One more thing to add here is that OOB install must be initiated by the client action and you cant force it.